# What is LINQ hosting and should I care?

Tags: linq, hosting

In terms of ISPs and webhosting, what is LINQ hosting? What does it give me as a developer or a site admin?

I've looked around and all the sites I found fail to explain what LINQ hosting is. They explain what LINQ is but fall short on the hosting part.

What are you using LINQ hositng for?

EDIT 1: I know what LINQ is and love it! Why are ISPs offering something inherent in the framework?

Edit 2: Examples include:
http://winhost.com/

http://www.arvixe.com/linq_hosting

http://www.windowshostingasp.net/Hosting_ASP.NET_plans/Hosting_ASP_NET_LINQ.aspx - from their website, "The ASP.NET LINQ Hosting plan means that the Windows hosting provider support MS LINQ (Language Integrated Query) hosting."

Comment: Can you point us to an example?

Comment: Maybe they support .Net 3.5?  Sounds like marketing gone wrong.

Comment: It probably just means they have the latest .NET frameworks, they run SQL server, and they might even provide support for configuring Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entity solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cheap trick for advertising.

Linq is getting to be a hot subject and they try to score easy contracts with managers that have no clue except that the tech people said they used linq for the new project ;)

I mean "Fully adheres to all LINQ hosting system requirements", what requirements?

Does that mean that if I need a linq provider for an old Paradox database they do that  :D

Answer (score 1):

Linq is hosted by the .NET framework. It isn't something an ISP needs to offer or can offer.